# Timestamp to DateTime conversion

Tags: c#, .net, system.diagnostics

I've used the System.Diagnostics namespace to do some performance logging with a customer who has issues with our software.

I've set things up so that .NET automatically adds the current Timestamp to the log entry `traceOutputOptions="Timestamp"` but am unable to convert the timestamp back to datetimes for display (it always gives me dates from the year 0000).

That didn't seem much of an issue since the documentation says it's just ticks from `DateTime.Now`. So even if they're relative I thought I would be able to at least determine the timespan between two entries.

I've now added the DateTime flag to the configuration in an attempt to figure out how to do it and it seems like these stupid diagnostics timestamps are 300 nanoseconds instead of 100 ns. Is this always the case? Because I *really* do not want to go back to the customer and redo the logging!

**EDIT:** Uhm code... Not sure what you want to see. Here's the new app.config section:

```
<system.diagnostics>
<trace autoflush="true" indentsize="3" />
<sources>
  <source name="Application" switchValue="All">
    <listeners>
      <remove name="Default" />
      <add name="shared" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
  <source name="Library" switchValue="All">
    <listeners>
      <remove name="Default" />
      <add name="shared" />
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
  <add name="shared"
       type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
       initializeData="app.log"
       traceOutputOptions="Timestamp,DateTime" />
</sharedListeners>
</system.diagnostics>
```

and this is where I'm trying to turn the Timestamp into DateTime:

```
long lTS = Int64.Parse(strTS);
var dt = new DateTime(lTS);
```

Comment: Can you please show the relevant code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a10k7w6c(v=vs.110).aspx), the Timestamp written is the return value of the `GetTimestamp` method of the `Stopwatch` class.

> Timestamp | Write the timestamp, which is represented by the return value of the [GetTimestamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.gettimestamp(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

This means that it's **not** a unix timestamp, but the number of ticks in the timer:

> Gets the current number of ticks in the timer mechanism.

Note that the number you get is dependent on the timer resolution, as mentioned in the remarks of the [`GetTimeStamp()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.gettimestamp(v=vs.110).aspx) method documentation:

> If the [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class uses a high-resolution performance counter, GetTimestamp returns the current value of that counter. If the Stopwatch class uses the system timer, GetTimestamp returns the current DateTime.Ticks property of the DateTime.Now instance.

So this is not a `DateTime` value, but a `TimeSpan` value.

Use the DateTime value that you already have instead, since you specified the `DateTime` option in the `traceOutputOptions` configuration.

Comment: The OP did not add the DateTime value to the log at first. There lies the problem. I'm afraid he will have to redo the performance session to get proper values.

Comment: Now that you've written in I saw it in the text of the question. if it was well formatted I would probably not miss that easily. However, I still think my answer could help him understand and fix his problem.

Comment: The problem is when I add both the DateTime and the Timestamp flags the two values don't match up with what the documentation says. My Timestamp values are not TimeSpan ticks. Why?

Comment: they are dependent on the stopwatch resolution, it's stated on the remarks section I've copied here.

Comment: OK. I've found that I can read the Frequency property through Powershell if I need to. Thanks for pointing me the right way!